# Attaching an image to an overlay using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have searched several posts but cannot find something similar to what I need to do, or what I have found I cannot get to work - pretty sure that is just me though!
So, there are 3 links on a page. When a link is clicked it should display the photo (on the same page) with an overlay applied to it. I can get the image to open but for the life of me cannot figure out how to get the overlays to attach. When the image opens it should stay on the same page (with the links visible through the overlay). The user should be able to click a close button or the image itself to go back to the links display.

I know the code is a mess as I've been trying anything I can think of to try and get this to work, since I'm currently stuck on getting everything to display properly and have not even gotten to the close function yet if someone can give me a hint I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Image preview  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="preview.css">
  <script src="preview.js"></script>
  <script>

    window.onload = function() {
      Preview.init();
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="https://courses.oreillyschool.com/advancedjavascript 
      /homework/images/image1.jpg" data-preview="image1">Mt. Rainier, 
      1</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://courses.oreillyschool.com/advancedjavascript
     /homework/images/image2.jpg" data-preview="image2">Mt. Rainier, 
     2</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://courses.oreillyschool.com/advancedjavascript
     /homework/images/image3.jpg" data-preview="image3">Mt. Rainier, 
     3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    .previewOverlay {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .previewOverlay img {
      position: relative;
      border: 20px solid white;
      border-radius: 10px;
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
    }
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      color: #fdfdfd;
      font-size: 50px;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    }
    .close:after {
      content: "\2717";
    }
   .close:hover {
      color: orange;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
 function Preview () {
 var mtnPics = document.querySelectorAll("a");
 console.log(mtnPics); 
 mtnPics.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  }); 

 for (var i = 0; i < mtnPics.length; i++) {
  mtnPics[i].onclick = showPicture;
}    

function showPicture (pictureURL) {
  var picPicked = document.getElementById("a").value;
  console.log(picPicked);

 //Create Div's for image display. 
 var ul = document.getElementById("ul");       
 var picDiv = document.createElement("div");
 picDiv.setAttribute("class", "previewOverlay");
 var imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
 imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "previewOverlay img");

 var imgSelected = document.getElementById("a").value;
 console.log(imgSelected);

 imgDiv.src = imgSelected;

 var buttonClose = document.createElement("button");

 //Assign divs and buttons
 buttonClose = document.setAttribute("class", "close");

 ul.appendChild(imgDiv); 
 imgDiv.appendChild(pictureURL);
 imgDiv.appendChild(buttonClose); 
 picDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);

 picDiv.insertBefore(ul, picDiv.firstChild);

 //document.body.appendChild(picDiv);

 buttonClose.onclick = closePicture;
  }


 function closePicture(targetURL) {
   document.removeElement('picDiv');
 }  

}
```

Comment: Why homebrew it when there are a thousand Lightbox scripts out there that require just a few lines of code?  Here's just one of many:  http://fancybox.net/

Comment: As @bpeterson76 says, there's little point re-inventing the wheel.  However, a quick scan of your code shows one minor fault, in that `ul.appendChild(imgDiv)` is adding a `<div>` element as a direct child of a `<ul>` element, which isn't allowed.  Only `<li>` can be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: @bpeterson76 I think he is doing this as a learning experience (looking at the image links), but needs a little help to get past a road block.

Comment: You are also using things like `getElementById("a")`, but you don't have any elements with `id="a"` for instance... you need to give the elements **unique** id's that you can then use to pick up with `gerElementById`.  You can also use `getElementsByClassName` which would allow you to get lots of elements with the same `class="sharedClassName"` for instance

Comment: Checkout [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/tuqelotolu/1/) of your code and try to make it complete. i.e without errors in the Console tab.

Comment: I was trying to help you, but this code is nonsense, try to make working demo on something like jsfiddle, it would be much easier

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, especially for the info regarding elements and how they are handled. I'm sorry that the code is not up to par, I'm just learning and have to use the code that I was given to complete the assignment.